# Unable to add and include resources at compile time in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to add an image to a C++ application. In the solution explorer by clicking `New Item -> Resource` created `Resource.rc` file. In the `Resource View` added new resource, ie a `Bitmap` image. The `resource.h` file is

```
#define IDB_BITMAP1                     101

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        102
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40001
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

Resource.rc - relevant part

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENN)LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_INDIA
// Bitmap
IDB_BITMAP1             JPG                     "Street.jpg"
#endif    // English (India) resources
```

The program runs without error inside the IDE. But when executed the exe generated by build, it seems the resource image file is not found. I am not able to  include resources at compile time.

### update

C++ sample code to load image and generate output image

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Open_eVision_2_11.h"
using namespace Euresys::Open_eVision_2_11;
using namespace std;
int main(){
    EImageBW8 EBW8Image1; // EImageBW8 instance
    // Display version - To make sure lib is included properly.
    std::cout << "Open eVison Version: " << Easy::GetVersion(); 
    try {
        EBW8Image1.Load("Street.jpg");
        EasyImage::Threshold(&EBW8Image1, &EBW8Image1, 140);
        EBW8Image1.SaveJpeg("output_image.jpg");
        std::cout << "\nImage generated!\n";
    }catch (const EException&) {
        std::cout << "Error: Possibly image not found!\n";
    }
}
```

When the program is executed inside the IDE, the program generated the output image. But when created an installer, using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/walkthrough-deploying-your-program-cpp?view=vs-2017), and installed using `Visual Studio Installer` and executing it is found that resource image not loaded properly. It prints out the library version and the catch part. Does this issues has something to related to the library, `Open_eVision_2_11.h`, used?

Comment: We will need more information! Can you show us the (relevant part of the) `.rc` (or `.rc2`) file that has the *actual* `IDB_BITMAP1` resource in it?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you getting a compile time error or a run time error?

Comment: @AdrianMole `IDB_BITMAP1             JPG                     "Street.jpg"`.

Comment: @user3389943 no error. But the resource image seems to be not found(Degub/Release build). So I need to manually input(paste) the image file into the build folder, so that it could run properly.

Comment: This line looks dodgy:  `#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENN)LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_INDIA` ... possible missing newline before `LANGUAGE` (but it could be an effect of pasting into the box here).

Comment: @AdrianMole "it could be an effect of pasting into the box here..." Yes :)

Comment: Please also show the code how you try to load/use the resource in your program. BTW, did you open your program in Visual Studio to look at the resources inside the program? Is the image visible then?

Comment: @WernerHenze updated the question. `"Is the image visible then?"` Yes.